# Why did Chat Room is deleted which is collection of comments?

Tags: support

I asked [Is it typical in small companies to BCC the CEO on all external mails?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/is-it-typical-in-small-companies-to-bcc-the-ceo-on-all-external-mails) question a few years back.

There were few useful comments. Those comments were [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79175/discussion-on-question-by-i-am-the-most-stupid-person-is-it-typical-in-small-com). I do not disagree with this because I know that comments are for just improve the question.

But I have curious that why moved chat deleted?

Comment: inactive rooms get frozen and after some time, if there are not enough stars, system automatically deletes.these

Answer (score 2):

From the [Chat Room FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention)

> **Will these rooms exist forever?**
>
> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

Since your deleted chat room only had 13 message, it was cleaned up by the chat admin bot.

Comment: How did you know that it had only 12 messages? That means, even deleted chat groups are visible to moderators?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct, although we only rarely need to go looking at deleted rooms.